# Gem5 cache dump

Tags: operating-system, system, cpu-architecture, gem5

How can we get all the data in different level of cache dumped in a file in gem5 ?
or something through which we can analyse the data in the cache like we can analyse the pipeline with the help of.

```
    util/O3-pipeview.py m5out/pipeview.txt --color -w150
    less -r o3-pipeview.out
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use the debug flag "**Cache**" in gem5 to understand the *icache* and *dcache* output.
I have tried with the following below steps:

1. connect to the gem5 base directory.
2. type the below command on the terminal -

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt --debug-flags=DRAM,Exec,Cache --debug-file=cache_pipe ./configs/example/se.py -c ./tests/test-progs/hello/bin/arm/linux/hello
```

the output file ***cache_pipe*** is generated in the ***m5out*** folder.
It will look like -

```
2000: system.cpu.icache: sendMSHRQueuePacket: MSHR ReadReq [44c:44f] IF                              
2000: system.cpu.icache: createMissPacket: created ReadCleanReq [440:47f] IF from ReadReq [44c:44f] IF
2000: system.mem_ctrls.dram: Timing access to addr 1088, rank/bank/row 0 0 0                   
2000: system.mem_ctrls.dram: Activate at tick 2000                                        
2000: system.mem_ctrls.dram: Activate bank 0, rank 0 at tick 2000, now got 1 active          
2000: system.mem_ctrls.dram: Schedule RD/WR burst at tick 27500                             
46250: system.mem_ctrls.dram: number of read entries for rank 0 is 0                         
77000: system.cpu.icache: recvTimingResp: Handling response ReadResp [440:47f] IF
77000: system.cpu.icache: Block for addr 0x440 being updated in Cache                          
77000: system.cpu.icache: Block addr 0x440 (ns) moving from  to state: 6 (E) writable: 1 readable: 1 dirty: 0 | tag: 0 secure: 0 valid: 1 | set: 0x11 way: 0                                 
79000: system.cpu: T0 : 0x1044c @_start    :   mov   fp, #0             : IntAlu :  D=0x0000000000000000                                                                        
79000: system.cpu.icache: access for ReadReq [450:453] IF hit state: 6 (E) writable: 1 readable: 1 dirty: 0 | tag: 0 secure: 0 valid: 1 | set: 0x11 way: 0                                    
85000: system.cpu: T0 : 0x10450 @_start+4    :   mov   lr, #0             : IntAlu :  D=0x0000000000000000                                                                         
85000: system.cpu.icache: access for ReadReq [454:457] IF hit state: 6 (E) writable: 1 readable: 1 dirty: 0 | tag: 0 secure: 0 valid: 1 | set: 0x11 way: 0                                  
87000: system.cpu.dcache: access for ReadReq [8de50:8de53] miss                               
89000: system.cpu.dcache: sendMSHRQueuePacket: MSHR ReadReq [8de50:8de53]
89000: system.cpu.dcache: createMissPacket: created ReadSharedReq [8de40:8de7f] from ReadReq [8de50:8de53]
```

Here I am using DRAM, Exec and Cache flags, one can use just Cache to get the information on icache and dcache.
And I have used precompiled hello executable you can use your own set of executable.